# Geometric interpretation of non-square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I realize that a $n\times{n}$ matrix can be interpreted as linear transformation of a vector in n-dimensional coordinate system.

But I am not able to interpret any $m\times{n}$ matrix same way since $m\times{n}$ doesn't mention all the coordinates. How  can this type of transformation be visualized?

Comment: A linear transformation between a space of dimension $n$ and one of dimension $m$.

Comment: See [Transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Matrices are a concise way of writing linear transformations. Matrix multiplication of a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ results in a new vector $x'\in\mathbb{R}^n$ that lies in the same space as the original vector (i.e. $Mx=x'$).

Now consider the multiplication of a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$; the resulting vector $x'$ no longer lies in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ but in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (i.e. $x$ has been mapped from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$).

For intuition on what this means, consider the matrix multiplication of a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ and a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$ The results $x'$ lines in $\mathbb{R}$--the vector has been mapped from an $n$-dimensional vector to a scalar value!

Your concern about the result not having the same dimensions as the original is not unfounded--indeed, we have lost potentially valuable information about the original vector by representing it in a lower dimensional space.